# How to make a text Field on user's click

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want my application to make a text box where ever a user clicks. So how do i synthesize a text box on demand. Kind of like in OneNote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how do i synthesize a text box on demand.

You create a text view or text field, and then you add it to your view wherever you want it. Assuming that you have the click event in `event` and you know the `width` and `height` of the text view you want to create, do this:

```
NSPoint *p = [myContainerView convertPoint:[event locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(p.x, p.y, width, height);
NSTextView *tv = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[myContainerView addSubview:tv];
```

Answer (score 1):

For detecting mouse event

```
 NSUInteger pmb = [NSEvent pressedMouseButtons];  
/*
A return value of 1 << 0 corresponds to the left mouse button, 1 << 1 corresponds to the right mouse button, 1<< n, n >=2 correspond to other mouse buttons.
*/

 NSPoint mouseLocation =   [NSEvent mouseLocation];
/*
Reports the current mouse position in screen coordinates.
*/
```